# org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: NULL not allowed for column "BACKLOG_ID"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm trying to map my **Backlog** class with the **Projecttask** class using the same backlog_id so it will be easy to access. When I'm doing it by putting backlog_id,  I'm getting this error: 
`org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: NULL not allowed for column BACKLOG_ID;`

What I have for now:

**Project class:**

```
@Entity
public class Project {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @NotBlank(message="project name is required")
    private String projectName;
    @NotBlank(message="project Identifier is required")
    @Size(min=4,max=5,message="please use 4to 5 character")
    @Column(updatable=false ,unique=true)
    private String projectIdentifir;
    @NotBlank(message="project description is required")
    private String description;
    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-mm-dd")
    private Date create_date;
    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-mm-dd")
    @Column(updatable=false)
    private Date upate_date;
    //@Autowired

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="project")
    //@Autowired
    //Backlog backlog=new Backlog();
    @JsonIgnore
    private Backlog backlog;

    @PrePersist
    protected  void onCreate()
    {
        this.create_date=new Date();
    }
    @PreUpdate
    protected void onUpdate()
    {
        this.upate_date=new Date();
    } 

    //Getters + Setters
}
```

**Projecttask class:**

```
@Entity
public class Projecttask {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(updatable=false)
    private String projectSequence; 
    @NotBlank(message="please include a project summary")
    private String summary;
    private String acceptanceCriteria;
    private String status;
    private Integer priority;
    private Date dueDate;
    private Date create_At;
    private Date update_At;
    @Column(updatable=false)
    private String projectIdentifir;
    //ManyToOne with Backlog
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.REFRESH)
    @JoinColumn(name="backlog_id",nullable=false,updatable=false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Backlog backlog;

    @PrePersist
    protected void onCreate() {
        this.create_At=new Date();

    }
    @PreUpdate
    protected void onUpdate() {
        this.update_At=new Date();
    }

    //Getters + Setters     

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Projecttask [id=" + id + ", projectSequence=" + projectSequence + ", summary=" + summary
                + ", acceptanceCriteria=" + acceptanceCriteria + ", status=" + status + ", priority=" + priority
                + ", dueDate=" + dueDate + ", create_At=" + create_At + ", update_At=" + update_At
                + ", projectIdentifir=" + projectIdentifir + ", backlog=" + backlog + "]";
    }
}
```

**Backlog class:**

```
@Entity
public class Backlog {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private Integer PTSequence=1;
    private String projectIdentifir;
    // with project
    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="project_id",nullable=false)
    //@Autowired
    @JsonIgnore
    private Project project;

    //OneTOMany projectTask
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="backlog")
    private List<Projecttask> projecttask=new ArrayList<>();

    //Getters + Setters     
}
```

**ProjectTaskService class:**

```
    @Service
    public class ProjectTaskService {
        @Autowired
     private BacklogRepository backlogRepository;
        @Autowired
     private ProjecttaskRepository projecttaskRepository;

    public Projecttask addProjecttask(String projectIdentifir,Projecttask projecttask){
        //Exception:project not found
        //Pts to be added to a specific project!==null(project)
        Backlog backlog=backlogRepository.findByProjectIdentifir(projectIdentifir);
        //set the bl to pt
        projecttask.setBacklog(backlog);
        System.out.println(backlog);
        // we want our project sequence to be like this  IDPRO-1,IDPRO-2,...100101
        //System.out.println(backlog.getPTSequence());
        //Integer BacklogSequence = backlog.getPTSequence();

        //update the bl sequnce 
        //BacklogSequence++;
        //Add Sequence to Project Task

        int counter=0;
        //projecttask.setProjectSequence(projectIdetifir+"-"+(++counter));
        projecttask.setAcceptanceCriteria(projectIdentifir+"-"+counter);
        counter=counter+1;
        //backlog.setPTSequence(counter);
        projecttask.setProjectIdentifir(projectIdentifir);
        //projectTask.setProjectIdentifir(projectIdentifir);
        //intial periority when peroirity is null
        if( projecttask.getPriority()==null) {
            projecttask.setPriority(3);
    }
        //initail status when status is null
        if(projecttask.getStatus()==null) {
            projecttask.setStatus("TO_DO");
        }

          return projecttaskRepository.save(projecttask);
    }

     public Iterable<Projecttask>findBacklogById(String id){
        return projecttaskRepository.findByProjectIdentifirOrderByPriority(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Apparently the JPA mappings seem to be ok. Let's see: 1) Have you checked that `Backlog backlog=backlogRepository.findByProjectIdentifir(projectIdentifir);` is not null? 2) Try adding @Transactional to the method signature

Comment: yes for Backlog backlog=backlogRepository.findByProjectIdentifir(projectIdentifir); is null it is not able to fetch backlog .I also  put @Transactional at method signature but it did not work .sir please help me i am stuck here since last 10 days.

Comment: @codependent   please help me sir on this issue this is very important for me

Comment: As you said, the actual problem is that the backlog, entity you are associating to the project task is null. You should have persisted it previously. Did you create it before? Have you checked that It actually exists in the db?

Comment: @codependent ,yes it exists in db and when i run project task it created before and exists in db.

Comment: link for the  class application.properties(https://ideone.com/VowRny)

Comment: link for the image of database backlog table is-(https://ibb.co/h9KJPqc)

Comment: Set the following logging levels at trace — org.hibernate.SQL org.hibernate.type — and check the sql statements for the execution of backlogRepository.findByProjectIdentifir(projectIdentifir);

Comment: @codependent after putting org.hibernate.SQL -org.hibernate.type -i am trying to debug it but could not this is a link what i am getting please help me on this-(https://ideone.com/fhYI66)

Comment: @codependent thanks for all your support i resolved my issue there was one logical error in Backlog backlog=backlogRepository.findByProjectIdentifir(projectIdentifir); projectIdentifir should be in upper case as it is in my whole project.

Comment: I’m glad you fixed it!!